# Make String from String[] and int

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

```
String callsign;
String airlines[] = {"DLH","BER","TUI","EZY","ACA","AAL","FDX","SKW","ABY","SWR"};
public void assignCallsign()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int airline = r.nextInt(10);
    int number = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
    callsign = airlines[airline] + number;
}
```

The String Array airlines[] contains 3 letters designating an airline.
The random integer airline is used to choose one of those airlines. The random integer number should designate the last 3 characters of an airplanes callsign.

I'm trying to get an output like "BER219", "AAL814" and so on, but upon executing the class, the String callsign is still null :/

Comment: Define _executing the class_.

Comment: I probably meant running, the german word translates into executing though :') [As in assignCallsign();]

Comment: Define _running the class_.

Comment: It isn't possible to tell what the problem is without a runnable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java passes variables by value. If you are testing the value of callsign variable outside this function then it will be null because you have set it to null outside of the assignCallsign method.

To remedy this, you can either:

- return the callsign value from the function and set a variable with it.

  ```
  public String assignCallSign() {
  return airlines[airline] + number;
  }
  String callsign = assignCallSign()
  ```
- make callsign a member variable of the class, and your code will function as you expect:

  ```
  private String callsign;
  ```

Comment: just to state the obvious: your second code sniplet returns a String and is therefore not public VOID assignCallSign()

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see the issue without seeing the class that is using it.

Speculating this is part of some "Flight" object. This demonstrates the callsign being set and displayed correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flight flight = new Flight();
    flight.assignCallsign();
    System.out.println(flight);
}

private static class Flight {
    private static final String AIRLINES[] = { "DLH", "BER", "TUI", "EZY", "ACA", "AAL", "FDX", "SKW", "ABY", "SWR" };
    private String callsign;
    public void assignCallsign() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int airline = r.nextInt(10);
        int number = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
        callsign = AIRLINES[airline] + number;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight [callsign=" + callsign + "]";
    }
}
```

Output

```
Flight [callsign=SKW534]
```